# Should I encrypt Amazon S3 keys in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, aes

Would encrypting the S3 keys in my binary be a good idea? How?

Thanks!

Comment: You should. Of course you'll need to ship the method to decrypt them inside the app too, so it's not exactly 100% safe..

Comment: Why do you need to embed the s3 keys in the app at all?

Comment: @BenClayton, and by "not exactly 100% safe," you mean "not very hard to reverse engineer."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you **do not include** them in your app. Put them on a server with a REST based interface and limit the possibilities of the single user on the server side.

When the user gets you S3 credentials they will be able to abuse them! And they will always be able to get them when you include them in your app.

Comment: Not only is it a security concern you have to consider the possibility that you will need to update them at some point, if they are included in your binary you will have a much harder time reconnecting your users to your S3 bucket.